# The definition of compact set without using open cover

Tags: analysis

In history, I know the definition of compact set comes from Heine-Borel Theorem in $R$, so it is natural that we define the compact set w.r.t open cover. I am curious what if we use any other set as the cover, what property will such definition of compact set be, since the compact set extend the concept of boundedness in finite dimensional, I think it maybe possible to redifine that without using open cover.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space#Equivalent_definitions may give some ideas

Comment: Consider the filter and ultrafilter definitions.

Comment: Every sequence has a convergent subsequence.

Comment: It's compact if all projections are closed. This is a more categorial definition.

Comment: The formulation in terms of open covers always having finite subcovers is really the "right" definition of compactness. It expresses that the spirit of compactness is that there aren't "too many" open sets in the topology, in the sense that a finite number will suffice to cover the space. For example, an infinite discrete space can't be compact because there are too many open sets (every point is open). You can think of the term "compact" as literally applying to the topology, not to the underlying point set.

Comment: @MPW I agree with the majority of your statement, but I think it should be noted that our intuition is highly dependent upon the topology being Hausdorff. The obvious example is that all affine schemes are compact in the Zariski topology, but few of our usual 'compactness' results hold in the non-Hausdorff context.